# How to detect and run custom scripts on docking / un-docking of ThinkPad?

Tags: linux, debian, thinkpad, dock, docking-station

I'd like to run custom scripts on docking or un-docking my ThinkPad X220.

Obvious place is some `udev` rule, but what events or attributes should I use? Another option is `acpi`. Is it better option? What else comes as viable alternative? I am running Debian, a mix between squeeze, backports, wheeze... and sid. Is there any native solution?

Comment: I have no way to test this myself but here's a suggestion: look through the messages generated by the kernel `dmesg` or syslog messages to check what messages are generated when you dock/undock.  If you do see a notification you should be able to tie the event that generates the message to your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the right tool on top of `udev` (and other low level interfaces like `sysfs`), configurable to everyone's taste. It's called `laptop-mode-tools` one of zilions of Debian packages (available for other distros at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop_Mode_Tools).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ACPI events to hook into the docking/undocking events if you install the ThinkPad kernel module: https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/hooking-into-docking-undocking-events-to-run-scripts/